# WAP2 not working: Critical Tunnel Failure

Tags: java, networking, blackberry, blackberry-jde

I'm developing an app for Blackberry but I'm stuck with something.
I wanna use WAP2 to connect to the world, but I get this error:

```
Critical tunnel failure
```

I'm posting the code below:

```
private String connectionParameters() {
        if(WLANInfo.getWLANState() == WLANInfo.WLAN_STATE_CONNECTED) {
            return ";interface=wifi";
        } else {
            int coverageStatus = CoverageInfo.getCoverageStatus();
            ServiceRecord record = this.getWAP2ServiceRecord();
            if(record != null && (coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
                return ";deviceside=true;ConnectionUID=" + record.getUid();
            } else if((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_MDS) {
                return ";deviceside=false";
            } else if((coverageStatus & CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) == CoverageInfo.COVERAGE_DIRECT) {
                return ";deviceside=true";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I really hope it's not Vodafone who's blocking WAP2 :(
Thanks in advance to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got confirmation from Vodafone Albania. WAP is limited to their services, so there's no error in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Check that proper APN settings are populated on your device. The settings are wireless provider specific, so contact Vodafone for the settings you need OR try to google on this (most likely you'll find them publicly available).

Comment: Arhimed, does the APN need to be put in for WAP2 to work? Aren't those two separate connection channels? I'll give it a shot right now.

Comment: Nope. They're not related at all :(

Comment: I vaguely recall one of my customers solved similar WAP2 issue on his real device by using right APN settings. However (1) I may be mistaken since it was months ago and (2) it might be a solution for his specific case only. OK, at least you tried this. My advice would be to install RIM's Network Diagnostic Tool and to see what it says. Check the http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800563/What_Is_-_Network_Diagnostic_Tool.html?nodeid=1450596&vernum=0